# How does TransitionListener work?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-transitions

Im trying to understand Lollipop transition and the TransitionListener so I have created 2 simples activities. Activity A and Activity B. Activity A starts acitvity B.

Activity A has a small green box at the bottom of the page.
Activity B has a big green box at the top of the page

The move transition works smooth and fine as expected.

In Activity B I am adding TransitionListener for SharedElementEnterTransition and SharedElementReturnTransition.

My expectation is that when entering Acitivity B, onTransitionStart and onTransitionEnd for the "enter listener" shall execute and when returning from Activity B the onTransitionStart and onTransitionEnd shall execute for the "return listener". But thats not the case, both listeners are executed when entering and returning.

Any help about why it is working like this is appreciated.

I have added some system prints and here is whats printed when entering Activity B:

```
12:59:22.686 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Enter
12:59:22.686 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Return
12:59:23.000 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Enter
12:59:23.000 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Return
```

Printous when returning from Activity B:

```
13:01:27.584 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Enter
13:01:27.584 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Return
13:01:27.894 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Enter
13:01:27.894 #¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Return
```

My expectation is that only printing "Enter" when entering activity A and "Return" when returning from Activity B.

Here is my code:

Activity A:

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    private Activity mActivity;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_a);

        mActivity = this;

        final View greenBox = findViewById(R.id.green_box_bottom);
        greenBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ActivityB.class);
                ActivityOptions options = ActivityOptions
                        .makeSceneTransitionAnimation(mActivity, greenBox, "move-green-box");

                startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Activity B:

```
public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

        getWindow().getSharedElementEnterTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                System.out.println("#¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Enter");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                System.out.println("#¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Enter");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });

        getWindow().getSharedElementReturnTransition().addListener(new Transition.TransitionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTransitionStart(Transition transition) {
                System.out.println("#¤ ActivityB.onTransitionStart - Return");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionEnd(Transition transition) {
                System.out.println("#¤ ActivityB.onTransitionEnd - Return");
            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionCancel(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionPause(Transition transition) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTransitionResume(Transition transition) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Layout Activity A:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityA">

<View
    android:id="@+id/green_box_bottom"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:transitionName="move-green-box"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout Activity B:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ActivityB">

<View
    android:id="@+id/green_box_bottom"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:transitionName="move-green-box"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't set a ReturnTransition the Enter transition will be used as the ReturnTransition. So you're essentially setting two listeners on the same transition. Try setting a different transition for the ReturnTransition, and see if that doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Thansk for your answer, I have not been able to test your suggestion yet. Will reply as soon as I have tested it

Comment: For some reason both the SharedElementEnterTransition and SharedElementReturnTransition listeners are getting called when going from Activity A to B. I thought only the SharedElementEnterTransition listener should be called. How do you fix this?